# ng-change to compare with previous value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<input ng-model="name" ng-change=change() placeholder="name">
<button ng-click="check()"> 
$scope.name = 'Default';

$scope.change = function(i){
console.log(i)
}
```

How to check $scope.name is still equal to `Default` using ng-change in angularjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input ng-model="name" ng-change=change() placeholder="name">
<button ng-click="check()"> 

$scope.name = 'Default';
var oldV = $scope.name;
$scope.change = function(i){
    if($scope.name === oldV) {
        console.log('same');
    } else {
        // update oldV here to latest if you want
    }
}
```

But for this purpose $watch should be better.
I don't think ng-change keeps track of your variable.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: why I need to use $watch since I'm doing everything in my same scope?

Comment: what if I need more than one input? use ng-change for all of them?

Comment: $scope.$watch is for same scope.
It will run the callback whenever the watched value is changed and when your task is done you can just stop the watcher.

Comment: you can do ng-change for all of then with custom logic, but you can use $watch with single logic. like
`$scope.$watch('name', cbFn);
$scope.$watch('lname', cbFn);`

Comment: `function cbFn(newValue, oldValue) { if(newValue !== oldValue) console.log('its different');}`